# How do I begin to troubleshoot Symbol or String expected, but nilClass given?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is in production and the blog page only is getting a 500 error. The Heroku log files say this:

```
017-11-21T19:04:10.618353+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.618254 #4] DEBUG -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]    (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blogs"
2017-11-21T19:04:10.628750+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.628603 #4] DEBUG -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]   Blog Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "blogs".* FROM "blogs" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 5], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2017-11-21T19:04:10.631373+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.631297 #4]  INFO -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]   Rendered blogs/_admin_actions.html.erb (0.9ms)
2017-11-21T19:04:10.632644+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.632567 #4]  INFO -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]   Rendered collection of blogs/_blog.html.erb [5 times] (3.1ms)
2017-11-21T19:04:10.632805+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.632739 #4]  INFO -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]   Rendered blogs/index.html.erb within layouts/blog (16.1ms)
2017-11-21T19:04:10.633090+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.633020 #4]  INFO -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
2017-11-21T19:04:10.634643+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.634573 #4] FATAL -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]
2017-11-21T19:04:10.634747+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.634675 #4] FATAL -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] ActionView::Template::Error (Symbol or String expected, but NilClass given.):
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635079+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.635014 #4] FATAL -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     4:
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635081+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     5:     <%= render partial: 'blogs/admin_actions', locals: {blog: blog} %>
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635082+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     6:
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635083+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     7:     <p><%= markdown blog.body %></p>
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635083+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     8:
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635084+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     9:  </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635166+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.635106 #4] FATAL -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635268+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.635198 #4] FATAL -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] app/helpers/blogs_helper.rb:8:in `block_code'
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635270+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] app/helpers/blogs_helper.rb:23:in `render'
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635271+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] app/helpers/blogs_helper.rb:23:in `markdown'
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635272+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] app/views/blogs/_blog.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_blogs__blog_html_erb___2264044015187904428_50852620'
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635273+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] app/views/blogs/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_blogs_index_html_erb__3065153368905289675_52150720'
2017-11-21T19:04:10.806557+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dancortes-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=4d778605-235a-4a14-9d31-ab7c89f35015 fwd="69.141.168.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
```

A colleague says that there must be a syntax error in _admin_actions.html.erb:

```
<% if logged_in?(:site_admin) %>
    <nav class="breadcrumb blogcrumb">
        <%= link_to fa_icon('file-text'), toggle_status_blog_path(blog), style: blog_status_color(blog) %> 
        <%= link_to fa_icon('pencil-square-o'), edit_blog_path(blog) %> 
        <%= link_to fa_icon('trash'), blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </nav>
<% end %>
```

I do not see a syntax error here, I did not even touch the code when this happened. Initially, I thought it was an error in the markdown of one of the blogs, but I have since deleted the blog and I still get a 500 error for the blog page only and only when logged in as admin.

I have edited this post to display the app/helpers/blogs_helper.rb:

```
module BlogsHelper
    def gravatar_helper user
        image_tag "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email)}", width: 60
    end

    class CodeRayify < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
        def block_code(code, language)
            CodeRay.scan(code, language).div
        end
    end

    def markdown(text)
        coderayify = CodeRayify.new(filter_html: true, hard_wrap: true)

        options = {
            fenced_code_blocks: true,
            no_intra_emphasis: true,
            autolink: true,
            lax_html_blocks: true,
        }

        markdown_to_html = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(coderayify, options)
        markdown_to_html.render(text).html_safe
    end

    def blog_status_color blog
        'color: red;' if blog.draft?
    end
end
```

I implemented debugging with Pry and this was the result:

```
 3:     <p class="blog-post-meta">Published <%= distance_of_time_in_words(blog.created_at, Time.now) %> ago</a></p>
     4:
     5:     <%= render partial: 'blogs/admin_actions', locals: {blog: blog} %>
     6:
     7:     <% binding.pry %>
 =>  8:
     9:     <p><%= markdown blog.body %></p>
    10:
    11:  </div><!-- /.blog-post -->

[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fbc007b6880>>)> blog
=> #<Blog:0x007fbc0b4d86d0
 id: 10,
 title: "My Blog Post 9",
 body:
  "Gluten-free pug cloud bread raclette.\r\n\t\tSucculents intelligentsia banjo, selfies pork\r\n\t\tbelly mixtape selvage hexagon DIY try-hard\r\n\t\tdistillery 90's art party kombucha bicycle\r\n\t\trights. **Pour-over fashion** axe poutine tumblr 3\r\n\t\twolf moon franzen, fam plaid bespoke ethical\r\n\t\tramps post-ironic ugh dreamcatcher fanny pack.\r\n\t\tYuccie salvia unicorn, yr viral kogi air plant\r\n\t\tthundercats sartorial kickstarter prism blog\r\n\t\tsubway tile ugh. Kinfolk kogi VHS, paleo narwhal\r\n\t\tshabby chic man braid flannel. Selfies stumptown\r\n\t\tvenmo copper mug tousled four dollar toast.\r\n\t\tAffogato enamel pin vape whatever.",
 created_at: Mon, 02 Oct 2017 19:38:05 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 04 Oct 2017 13:20:53 UTC +00:00,
 slug: "my-blog-post-9",
 status: "draft",
 topic_id: 3>
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fbc007b6880>>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"blogs", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

Then with binding.pry inside the show action of the blogs_controller.rb:

```
def show
    binding.pry
    if logged_in?(:site_admin) || @blog.published?
      @blog = Blog.includes(:comments).friendly.find(params[:id])
      @comment = Comment.new

      @page_title = @blog.title
      @seo_keywords = @blog.body
    else
      redirect_to blogs_path, notice: "You are not authorized to access this page."
    end
  end
```

I tried this:

```
 3:     <p class="blog-post-meta">Published <%= distance_of_time_in_words(blog.created_at, Time.now) %> ago</a></p>
    4:
    5:     <%= render partial: 'blogs/admin_actions', locals: {blog: blog} %>
    6:
    7:     <p><%= markdown blog.body %></p>
 => 8:
    9:  </div><!-- /.blog-post -->

[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fbc007b6880>>)> @blog
=> nil
```

So does that mean the blogs are not being set?

Next, I tried placing `binding.pry` here:

```
def index
    binding.pry
    if logged_in?(:site_admin)
      @blogs = Blog.recent.page(params[:page]).per(5)
    else
      @blogs = Blog.published.recent.page(params[:page]).per(5)
    end
    @page_title = "Portfolio Blog"
  end
```

Not sure if the problem is in the index action, but I decided to add index action to `before_action`:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :toggle_status]
  before_action :set_sidebar_topics, except: [:update, :create, :destroy, :toggle_status]
  layout "blog"
  access all: [:show, :index], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit, :toggle_status]}, site_admin: :all
```

Now I get a 404 error, stating:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Blog without an ID):
```

So I would like to check in with you guys and see if it even looks like I am in the ballpark here.

Comment: The stack trace indicates the problem may be in blogs_helper.rb. What does that file contain? Please edit your answer to show that file.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code, but you could try removing lines one-by-one from your partial to see which one is giving you the error.

Comment: Are you certain that `blog.body` is a string value and not `nil`? I would put a `binding.pry` right before the `markdown blog.body` call to ensure you are passing in valid data to the method.

Comment: @anothermh, I put a ```binding.pry``` in front of the ```markdown blog.body``` and posted the results.

Comment: Great, now start debugging until you get to the problematic line of code  I recommend [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) for access to commands like `next` to step through.

Comment: I would follow what @Brian suggested and uncomment the code line by line  as suggested by the stack trace in ```blogs_helper.rb```.

Comment: I am doing this now because I tried ```Pry``` and it has not provided anything useful for me.

Comment: @Daniel, when I commented out ```CodeRay.scan(code, language).div```, the blog page worked fine again. Then I uncommented again and it seems to work fine again. So it seems coderay gem is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to resolve this utilizing `pry`, then take a look at the stack trace which indicates the problem to be in blogs_helper.rb

```
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635268+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.635198 #4] FATAL -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] app/helpers/blogs_helper.rb:8:in `block_code'
```

Comment out the code on line 8 and also the code indicated here:

```
2017-11-21T19:04:10.634747+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.634675 #4] FATAL -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072] ActionView::Template::Error (Symbol or String expected, but NilClass given.):
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635079+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-21T19:04:10.635014 #4] FATAL -- : [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     4:
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635081+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     5:     <%= render partial: 'blogs/admin_actions', locals: {blog: blog} %>
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635082+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     6:
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635083+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     7:     <p><%= markdown blog.body %></p>
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635083+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     8:
2017-11-21T19:04:10.635084+00:00 app[web.1]: [9091d983-bc39-4f64-b86e-c388e3893072]     9:  </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
```

Through a process of elimination via commenting out code, you should be able to narrow down the problem with your code.

In other words, since `pry` did not seem to work for you, then the next step was to implement delta debugging manually to solve this. Basically, commenting out chunks of code until you can work out what part of the code is causing the failure.